# Duplicate questions still show as "closed" when searching

Tags: bug, search, duplicate-questions

So a while ago duplicates started showing the more useful [duplicate] text in the question list and front page:
[image]

However when searching for questions, you still see [closed] on closed duplicates:

[image]

The search results should be updated to show duplicate status as well if at all possible.

Comment: This is going to get meta very quickly now if someone searches for this question.