# Duplicate questions show up as "closed" in search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, duplicate-questions

In search results, a duplicate question shows up with "[closed]" appended to its title instead of the expected "[duplicate]":

[image]

However, when I click on the question, it shows up correctly:

[image]

This has [happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165132/replace-closed-with-duplicate-in-search-results?lq=1) [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182734/duplicate-questions-still-show-as-closed-when-searching?rq=1), but it has apparently rose up again.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that recently closed duplicates show as "on hold" in the search results, which should also display as duplicate.

Comment: A couple days ago they were displaying properly...

Comment: Can be reproduced for [some questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=no+longer+accepting+questions), [but not others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers+not+sent). There's been some major work done on the search infrastructure today, so probably best to let it bake overnight.

Comment: @animuson Could you show me an example?

Comment: @gparyani http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E2%80%9CMulti-Collider+Thingy%E2%80%9D+doesn%27t+dropdown+on+question+pages+%28IE8%29

Comment: @animuson It now shows as "[closed]"...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace "closed" with "duplicate" in search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165132/replace-closed-with-duplicate-in-search-results)

Comment: That is already linked in the question. (As "happened") A regression of a previously working feature/bug is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was (temporarily) expected [as part of the change here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130997/add-a-duplicate01-search-operator/161787).  We successfully upgraded our elasticsearch cluster to 0.90.5 last night which brings a whole host of new features we'll be using.  Since we were doing that upgrade *anyway*, a full re-index for the `idDuplicate` boolean was in order, just after the upgrade.

A network-wide reindex is in progress and will complete over the next few hours, fixing up `duplicate:<bool>` status everywhere as well as the `[duplicate]` indicators in the titles for results.

Comment: I just noticed the same issue with my [deleted question list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198800/casing-issue-on-merged-questions). (Currently it shows as "[on hold]", but it will soon become "[closed]".)